# VBA search range for =TODAY()+30 and clear contents

Tags: excel, vba

Somewhat experienced with excel but very new to VBA and looking for some help. I have a range (D:AE) containing dates. Each column has a variable number of rows but the total number of used cells will be no less than ~1500 and may go as high as 10,000. I am trying to create a macro that will find any date within this range greater than 30 days from today and then subsequently clear that same cell's contents. The end result will be dates only falling within the next 30 days. I've done some pretty extensive searching but the limits of my experience haven't left me with much. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a For ... Next loop to look at every column in your sheet, like

```
For C = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
```

Nest another such loop inside the first, like,

```
For R = 2 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

Within this second loop, each cell is ActiveSheet.Cells(R, C) and you can test and manipulate it. Like,

```
With ActiveSheet.Cells(R, C)
    If IsDate(.Value) Then
        If CDate(.Value) > (Date + 30) Then
            .Value = ""
        End If
    End If
End With
```

Comment: That did exactly what I needed. Thanks so much!